# no me inserta todos los registro de la tabla

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una function en PostgreSQL que cuando ejecuto la function por primera ves me inserta todos los registro del otro servidor bien hasta ahí,pero cuando se insertan más registros en la table de ese servidor, y cuado ejecuto mi función nuevamente para tener esos registro la function se ejecuta bien pero no me inserta los registros que insertaton nuevo en dicha table, mi function es esta:

```
    create or replace function get_data_p(
    )
   returns void
   as $$
   declare
    v_info varchar(50):='no datos encontrados';
begin
perform dblink_connect('dbname=slave port=5432 host=192.168.56.101 user=postgres password=123');
perform dblink_open('p_cursor','select * from slave');
loop
perform dblink(
        'dbname=master port=5432 host=192.168.56.102 user=postgres password=123','
        update master set estatus =''C'' 
        where fecha between ''01-feb-2022'' and ''02-feb-2022'' ');
        
insert into master
(select *
from dblink_fetch('p_cursor',1000)
 
as (compania integer, nombre varchar(30),fecha date,estatus varchar(5)) 
            where not exists(select compania from master
                where compania=compania
                group by compania));
    
if not found then
raise notice '%',v_info;
end if;
exit;
end loop;
perform dblink_close('p_cursor');
perform dblink_disconnect();
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: **¿Porqué escribes todo en negrilla?** Hacerlo no le dará mayor visibilidad a tu pregunta ni hará que te respondan más rápido, sino todo lo contrario. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Saludos

Comment: buenas colega, con relacion a las letras en negrilla, no le di el sentido que usted le dio, pero gracias por el punto lo tendre presente para la proxima gracias.

Comment: algun error? revisaste los logs?

Comment: en el log no me dice nada,el detalle es que la function se ejecuta sin problema

Answer (score 0):

buenas colega ya resolvi el problema eran los alias , tambien como puedo hacer con esta misma function conectarme a varios servidores por lo menos a 5 servidores para insertar dichas informaciones esta es mi function:

```
create or replace function get_data_p(
)
returns void
as $$
declare
v_info varchar(50):='no datos encontrados';
begin
perform dblink_connect('dbname=slave port=5432 host=192.168.56.101 user=postgres password=123');
perform dblink_open('p_cursor','select * from slave ft');
loop
perform dblink(
'dbname=master port=5432 host=192.168.56.102 user=postgres password=123','
update master set estatus =''C''
where fecha between ''01-feb-2022'' and ''02-feb-2022'' ');

insert into master
(select *
from dblink_fetch('p_cursor' ,1000)

as ft (compania integer, nombre varchar(30),fecha date,estatus varchar(5))
where not exists(select c.compania,c.fecha from master c
where c.compania=ft.compania
and c.fecha=ft.fecha
group by c.compania));

if not found then
raise notice '%',v_info;
end if;
exit;
end loop;
perform dblink_close('p_cursor');
perform dblink_disconnect();
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```